# AndroidBillingLibrary's reliability

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, android-billing

I have one, simple question: Is robotmedia's inAppBilling [library](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) reliable and eligible to use, or would you rather suggest me classic inAppBilling [imlementation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that robotmedia's [library](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) you link to hasn't been updated for 7 months (At time of writing), and specifically states it only supports **V1 and V2** of GooglePlay In-App Purchase, I would suggest the [Google implementation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) which currently runs on **V3**, simply because of the more apparent update cycle.

V3 [improves the usability](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) making the whole system much easier to integrate with your application, so in terms of reliability I would put forward that you are less likely to introduce bugs of your own in a simpler implementation.

There are plenty of resources showing you how to set up and get In App Billing working with Android through the Google Play libraries. (RobotMedia also as a tutorial themselves for their version).

You can read about implementing **Google Play Services** In App Billing [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html).

Comment: Thanks for a complete answer. Thats what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are better alternatives to robotmedia or classic implementation.

[OpenIAB](http://www.onepf.org/openiab) supports Google Play, Amazon, SamsungApps, Yandex.Store, Appland and based on Google v3 API.

Because of v3 inventory is managed by Appstore so you wouldn't lose your purchase even after crash or on poor internet connection

Simple step-by-step how-to is right on GitHub https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB 
Questions and answers are also on [GitHub](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/issues?direction=desc&sort=updated&state=open)

Comment: great, thanks. Is there also a way, how to accomplish expiration type purchase? Like when I want to provide the user to purchase and his purchase expires in f.e. 2 months

Comment: There is a built-in subscriptions functionality in v3. If you going to use it, Store will charge user every month or year. But as I know you cannot specify your own interval for such payments.

If you need exactly 2-monthes period probably it's better to provide consumable item "1 paid month", "2 paid month" and consider it as virtual currency like crystals or coins.

Or you can create several non-consumable items for following scheme:
item "first 2 monthes" for $2
item "next 4 months" for $3

Answer (score 1):

No.

I wrote it and I wouldn't use it for a new app.

That said, if I had to develop a new app for Android that required in-app billing, I would probably update the library.

Sadly, I don't foresee this happening anytime soon.

Whatever you use make sure it's built on top of the version 3 API.